# MongoDB Atlas & Realms with JWT Authentication (C# / .NET)

Tags: c#, mongodb, jwt, realm

I've set up a Database Cluster with MongoDB/Atlas. As authentication method, I want to use a JWT based solution.
While Atlas doesn't support JWT authentication, MongoDB Realms does. So I added a new Realm app, connected it to my Database Cluster and activated JWT authentication.

Now I can't find a way to use Realms from my .NET Core application. The MongoDB C# drivers only seem to work when using atlas but not realms. There is a Realms nuget-package but I don't know how to connect to MongoDB Realms.

Is there a way to user Atlas & Realms along with JWT authentication in a .NET Core app?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A beta of the [Realm .NET SDK](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/releases/tag/10.0.0-beta.1) was released in Oct. 2020 that allows you to connect to MongoDB Realm and use all supported authentication types.